# Ошибка в ajax-запросе

Tags: php, ajax

Добрый день
Начинаю разбираться с `AJAX`. Код вроде работает, но при попытке раскомментировать строку, где идет работа с базой данных, появляется ошибка:

> syntax error, unexpected <

Как организовать работу с БД в этом случае? Спасибо!

```
<?
//$rawPost = file_get_contents('php://input');
$rawPost = '[{"exam":"hist1_theme1","userID":0},{"Id":7,"Mark":0},{"Id":8,"Mark":0},{"Id":9,"Mark":0},{"Id":10,"Mark":0},{"Id":11,"Mark":0},{"Id":15,"Mark":0},{"Id":33,"Mark":0},{"Id":34,"Mark":0}]';

if ($rawPost)
{
    // Разбор пакета JSON
    $questsArray = json_decode($rawPost);
    $info = $questsArray[0];
    $currExam = $db->getExamByName($info->exam);
    array_shift($questsArray);
    //$currAttempt = $db->setAttempt($info->userID, $currExam['Id']);

    //foreach($questsArray as $quest){
    //    $db->setAnswers1($quest->Mark, $currAttempt, $quest->Id);
    //}

    $response = "YES";
}
else
{
    $response = "NO";
}

header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache');

echo json_encode($response);
```

Класс БД

```
function __construct($params){
    try {
        $this->_db = new PDO($params['db.conn'], $params['db.user'], $params['db.pass']);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Невозможно создать базу данных";
    }
}

function __destruct(){
    unset($this->_db);
}

protected function setDataToDB($sql){
    try{
        $result = $this->_db->exec($sql);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}

protected function getDataFromDB($sql){
    try{
        $result = $this->_db->query($sql);
        $fetchFunction = function() use($result){
                            return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        };
        return new FetchIterator($fetchFunction);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}

function getLogins(){
    $sql = "SELECT Login 
            FROM authorization 
            WHERE Deleted = false";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql);
}

function getAuthorization($login){
    $sql = "SELECT Password 
            FROM authorization 
            WHERE Login = '$login'";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql)->current();
}

function getUserFromDB($login){
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Login 
            FROM authorization 
            WHERE Login = '$login'";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql)->current();
}

function setNewUser($surname, $name, $patronymic, $isMale, $email, $phone, $login, $password, $salt, $iteration, $status){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons 
                (Surname, Name, Patronymic, IsMale, Email, Phone) 
            VALUES  
                ('$surname', '$name', '$patronymic', $isMale, '$email', '$phone')";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
    $id = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
    $hash = createHash($password);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO authorization 
                (Login, Password, Status, Id_persons) 
            VALUES 
                ('$login', '$hash', '$status', $id)";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
}

function getRegions(){
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Name 
            FROM catalogregions 
            WHERE Deleted = false";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql);
}

//*****************************
//Работа с тестами
//*****************************

function getQuestTypes(){
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Name
            FROM catalogquestionstype
            WHERE Deleted = false";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql);
}

function getQuestThemes(){
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Name, Caption
            FROM catalogquestionstheme
            WHERE Deleted = false";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql);
}

function getQuestThemeById($id){
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Name
            FROM catalogquestionstheme
            WHERE Id = $id AND Deleted = false";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql)->current();
}

function getExamByName($examName){
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Name
            FROM exams
            WHERE Name = '$examName' AND Deleted = false";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql)->current();
}

function getQuestions(){
    $sql = "SELECT
                questions1.Id, 
                questions1.Num_question, 
                questions1.MarkMax,
                questions1.Id_exams,
                catalogquestionstype.Name as Type,
                questions1.Image_Path,
                questions1.Question, 
                questions1.QuestionComment, 
                questionskeys.Answer as RightAnswer
            FROM questions1
                INNER JOIN questionskeys
                    ON questionskeys.Id_questions1 = questions1.Id
                INNER JOIN catalogquestionstype
                    ON catalogquestionstype.Id = questions1.Id_catalogQuestionType
            WHERE questions1.Deleted = false
            ORDER BY questions1.Id";
    return $this->getDataFromDB($sql);
}

function setQuestion($questNum, $markMax, $examId, $imgPath, $questType, $questTheme, $quest, $questComment, $answer){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO questions1
                (Num_question, MarkMax, Id_exams, Image_Path, Id_catalogQuestionType, Id_catalogQuestionTheme, Question, QuestionComment)
            VALUES
                ($questNum, $markMax, $examId, '$imgPath', $questType, $questTheme, '$quest', '$questComment')";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
    $newQuestID = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO questionskeys
                (Answer, Id_questions1)
            VALUES
                ('$answer', $newQuestID)";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
}

function setAttempt($userID, $examID){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO attempts
                (Id_persons, Id_exams)
            VALUES
                ($userID, $examID)";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
    $newAttemptID = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
    return $newAttemptID;
}

function setAnswers1($mark, $attemptID, $questionID){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO answers1
                (Mark, Id_attempts, Id_questions1)
            VALUES
                ($mark, $attemptID, $questionID)";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
}

function setExam($name){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO exams
                (Name)
            VALUES
                ('$name')";
    $this->setDataToDB($sql);
}
```

Сама функция javascripta выглядит так:

```
function sendAttempt(){
    var exam = "<?=$_GET['exam'];?>";
    var userID = "<?=$_SESSION['user']['Id'];?>" * 1;
    sendQuestsArray.unshift({exam: exam, userID: userID});
    var jsonAnswers = JSON.stringify(sendQuestsArray);
    console.log("jsonAnswers: " + jsonAnswers);
    var req = getXmlHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState != 4) return;
        var otz = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        console.log(otz);
    };
    req.open("POST", "/components/sendattempt.php", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    //req.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", jsonAnswers.length);
    req.send(jsonAnswers);
}
```

Comment: Что-то не воспроизводится, проблема точно в этом участке кода?

Comment: Да, так как при комментировании всех строк с db скрипт отрабатывается.

Comment: Возможно, ошибка не воспроизводится, потому что подключение к DB в другом файле? Я просто первый раз спрашиваю, не знаю, что прикладывать. Не все же файлы проекта?

Comment: в ошибке не указана файл и номер строки?  $db::setAttempt() - это ваш самописнный класс/метод, или используете что то публичное? Думаю ошибка где в одном из методов setAttempt или setAnswers1, ну или в самом файле/классе, ну и судя по ошибке, или лишний знак < или запрещены короткие теги <? Покажите что там за класс отвечает за работу с бд.

Comment: @Bookin Ошибка указывает на первую строку. Класс БД прикреплю в ответе, сюда не влезает. Короткие теги работают во всех остальных местах.

Comment: Ошибка также появляется при любом обращении к другому файлу через require и include. У меня ощущение, что это какая-то элементарная вещь, которую я не учел по незнанию.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, ответ нашелся, всем спасибо, кто пытался помочь.
Дело было в том, что функция обращения к БД отдавала текстовую ошибку с тегами. А ошибку она отдавала потому, что, как выяснилось, в файле php нужно было заново подключить все классы для работы с БД и заново создать переменную базы данных. После этого всё работает.

Однако, такое решение мне напоминает костыль. Хочу спросить у профессионалов: есть ли более элегантный метод, чем повторное подключение всех необходимых классов?